# General solution of the pde $UU_x + UU_y = x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

A general solution of the pde $UU_x + UU_y = x$ is of the form $f(u^2 -x^2 , {y \over (x+u)}) = 0 $ where  $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is $C^1$ and $\nabla f \neq 0$ for every point.

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem? I know the answer would have been correct if the part "$\nabla f \neq 0$ for every point" was not there. I really do not know what does it mean? and what is the relation with this problem?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the characteristics method

$$
\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{udu}{x}
$$

then

$$
\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}\Rightarrow y-x=C_1
$$

as well as

$$
\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{udu}{x}\Rightarrow  u^2-x^2 = C_2
$$

and finally

$$
f(x,y,u)=u^2-x^2 - \phi(y-x)=0
$$

Comment: I did not ask for a solution. Can you please check the question once more?@Cesareo

Comment: Try $v = \frac{1}{2}u^2$ instead. Then $dv = u u_x dx+u u_y dy= v_x dx + v_y dy$. Solve then for $v \to u$